# To confirm it’s ‘Thank you’ page after landing on a thank you page on a website using Cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am new to Cypress and I am learning it.

I want to confirm that I have landed on a ‘Thank you’ page after clicking on submit button and landing on thank you page.

How do I check this using Cypress.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So at first, you need to trigger a redirect into "Thank you page" you didn't describe a way of redirecting (click or simply straight open this page).

The easiest way to do this is just verify an **unique element** to this page is visible like:

`cy.get(*selector_unique_for_this_page*).should('be.visible')`

Another method is to **check url**
`cy.url().should('include', 'thank-you.html');`

Or you can validate also the **page title** by:

`cy.title().should('eq', 'Thank you page')`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Appreciate it!

Comment: So, after clicking on "Submit' button, I land on Thank you page

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses. Appreciate your help